# How does form_for model object with select_tag nest its params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I create an object with a `form_for` and put a `select_tag` inside it, I expect the selected value to go to params as a hash inside the model hash, e.g. `params[:model][:attribute1]`, since this is how really basic forms with text fields have behaved for me in the past. Not the case here:

```
<%= form_for(@vote, url: judgment_votes_path(@vote.judgment)) do |i| %>
<%= select_tag(:yayornay, options_for_select(%w[yes no undecided stand_aside])) %>
  <div class='actions'>
    <%= i.submit 'Save vote' %><br />
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Above gives me a `params[:yayornay]`. Apidock's entry on form_for has revealed little to dispel my confusion. Is there an easy way to structure my `select_tag` params like `params[:vote][:yayornay]`, so that everything's nice like old times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the select_tag helper, which simply makes the select tag syntax a bit easier to use.  Check out the form helpers here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html for select tags that correspond to an object (such as :vote in your case).  You can use the select helper either like select(:vote, :yayornay, ...) or i.select(:yayornay, ...)

FYI, it's more common to use 'f' as the form object, not 'i'.

Comment: This question has an excellent example for you to reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297941/creating-a-drop-down-list-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can EITHER use i.select like this:

```
<%= i.select :yayornay, ... %>
```

OR use select_tag like this:

```
<%= select_tag "vote[yayornay]", ... %>
```

When you use "i.select", rails build the prefix "vote" for you automatically since you are using the form object for @vote. If you don't want to use "i.select", you must manually specify the name of the select element yourself like above.

Hope this helps.