# Creating a drop down list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any one help me in creating a drop down list in rails. I'm having a user table with a  role field and I want to create a drop down list with values manager, investigator, director for role.How I can extract this value to parms[:role] . I'm new to rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using form_for (not form_tag), then it should go like this.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.select :role, options_for_select(%w[manager investigator director]) %>

<% end %>
```

Then you'll have `params[:user][:role]` available in your controller.

Refer [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) for more info on select helper.